# Como dizer "dia sim, dia não" de forma reduzida

Tags: expressões

Há alguma forma reduzida de dizer "dia sim, dia não"?

Se algo ocorre todas as semanas, podemos dizer semanalmente. Em inglês, quando ocorre dia sim, dia não, podemos dizer *every other day*. Então, estava pensando se existe alguma para para esse tipo de ocorrência: dia sim, dia não; frase sim, frase não; etc.

Comment: Pesquisei "dois dias" no Priberam usando "Pesquisar nas definições" e achei bulhufas; a palavra para "a cada 9 dias", "nundinário" tem na descrição "nove dias", então, se houvesse alguma para "a cada dois dias", provavelmente teria "dois dias". Então, duvido que haja uma tão específica. Contudo, podes usar *alternadamente*, a qual já se usa e já ouvi muita gente usando.

Comment: Porém, se aceitares neologismos, podem-se usar as regras morfológicas para "criar" palavras. São palavras com o sentido de "a cada X dias" *quinzenal* (de *quinzena*), *decendial* (de *decêndio*), *semanal* (de *semana*); embora *triduano* (de *tríduo*) signifique "durante três dias*. O dicionário Houaiss sufixou *quinquêndio* (período de cinco dias) com *-al*. Então faz sentido pegar a palavra que significa "período de dois dias" e sufixá-la com *-al*: *bíduo* → *bidual*. É facilmente confundível com *bi-* + *dual*, porém.

Comment: O neologismo não soa tão bem, fica bem difícil alguém perceber rapidamente o que quis dizer. Mas _alternadamente_ é uma boa alternativa para alguns casos.

Comment: @Schilive, se quiser adicionar seu comentário como resposta, posso aceitá-la.

Comment: Sidney, talvez depois de uma outra pesquisa. Vou apagar este comentário depois.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que pode ser "dias alternados" ou "dias alternos".

Do dicionário Priberam para [alternado](https://dicionario.priberam.org/alternados), especialmente a segunda definição:

al·ter·na·do
(particípio de alternar)
adjectivo

1. Que se alternou.
2. Um depois do outro; intercalado; interpolado.
   Confrontar: alternato.

"alternados", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/alternados [consultado em 16-09-2021].

Comment: O'Bieito, obrigado pela resposta, mas não vejo como "em dias alternados" poderia ser uma forma reduzida de "dia sim, dia não".

Comment: @Schilive, compreendo, mas na pergunta estava a comentar "every other day" como exemplo, que também não é muito reduzida; na minha ideia ele está também à procura de mais uma alternativa... Se calhar também alternadamente pode valer mas não é tão  específico...